# How to combine raster analysis algorithm?

Tags: python, qgis

I have two raster files stores in a variable called results.

```
results[file1] = outputs['QGIS Algorithm 1']['OUTPUT']
results[file2] = outputs['QGIS Algorithm 2']['OUTPUT']
```

Is it possible to use this as an input to the raster calculator algorithm. Something along the lines

```
alg_params = {
            'CELLSIZE': 0,
            'CRS': None,
            'EXPRESSION': '0.3*"results[file1]@1"+0.7*"results[file1]@1"',
            'EXTENT': None,
            'LAYERS': 'some layer,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['RasterCalculator'] = processing.run('qgis:rastercalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Vulnerability'] = outputs['RasterCalculator']['OUTPUT']
```